# Can distmaker be run off a specific branch

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit

I was using distmaker.sh (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/distmaker/distmaker.sh) to generate tarballs for testing.

I had my local branches all set to 4.6 (core, drupal, joomla and wordpress) however, distmaker switched to the master branch when building the files.  I had created a buildkit drupal install and then cloned the joomla and wordpress repos into /sites/all/modules/civicrm/

Is there a setting to build the tarballs off a specific branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the settings in distmaker.conf, the ones at the end. They specify the git branch to pull from:

```
## Git branch/tag name
DM_REF_CORE=master
DM_REF_DRUPAL=7.x-${DM_REF_CORE}
DM_REF_DRUPAL6=6.x-${DM_REF_CORE}
DM_REF_JOOMLA=${DM_REF_CORE}
DM_REF_WORDPRESS=${DM_REF_CORE}
DM_REF_PACKAGES=${DM_REF_CORE}
```

Comment: once you have it working, can you please mark the question as answered :)